# Tools to monitor PHP usage from the terminal

Tags: php, mysql, performance, server

Are there any tools that allow me to monitor the performance of an application in php: Visits, how much ram or cpu a visitor consumes, how much network speed, etc. In real time from terminal?

Comment: What's your goal? In most cases, the average visitor is going to occasionally (a couple times a minute, perhaps) consume a couple hundred milliseconds of CPU time, and some RAM for that same amount of time. For visit, you'd want an analytics solution.

Comment: There is an application (GroupOffice) in PHP (and Mysql). There is a module, which allows me to link a mailbox using IMAP and this module works like a webmail.

When I consult the webmail and check (or open a message) a request is made, the normal loading time of this request is 500ms, however at certain times the loading time goes to 2 or 15 seconds. There are very fast moments, where each request is executed at 250ms.

The application is mounted on a VPS 4 vCPU Cores (8 GB RAM) 250GB SSD. It is only being used by 20 users at the same time.

I would like to monitor it to know what happe

Comment: Stack Overflow discourages questions asking for tool recommendations. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: I would fit this question, in this part which is referenced and valid.
"software tools commonly used by programmers; and is"

Comment: You should consider enabling slow query logging in MySQL as an early step.

Comment: Windows?  Unix?  Mac?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use some tools  like PHP Performance Monitoring Tool. these kinds of tools you can use to monitor and track the performance of an applications in php.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).